# Svg animation doesn't play in Mozilla properly

Tags: jquery, svg, mozilla, svg-animate

I have a page that loads a SVG file as loading image and then goes to home screen. The SVG animation plays in Chrome and Opera but not in Mozilla.

I typed all the keyframes but didnt worked.Any suggestions?
Mozilla is the latest update.

Here is the code of the SVG

```
 <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 1224 260.429" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1224 260.429;"
 xml:space="preserve">

<defs>
<style type="text/css">
<![CDATA[
.st0{fill:#FFFFFF;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:5;}
.st1{fill:#FFFFFF;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:5;}
.st2{fill:none;}
]]>


.st0{
   stroke-dasharray: 2000;
 stroke-dashoffest: 0;
-webkit-animation:dash 7s linear forwards;
-o-animation:dash 7s linear forwards;
-moz-animation:dash 7s linear forwards;
animation:dash 7s linear forwards;

}


.st1
{
 stroke-dasharray: 2000;
 stroke-dashoffest: 0;
-webkit-animation:dash 7s linear forwards;
-o-animation:dash 7s linear forwards;
-moz-animation:dash 7s linear forwards;
animation:dash 7s linear forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes dash{
from{
 stroke-dashoffset: 2000;
}
to{
 stroke-dashoffset: 0;

}
}







</style>

    </defs>
<rect x="29.56" y="44.941" class="st2" width="532.002" height="215.487"/>
<g>
<g>
    <path class="st0" d="M66.223,159.693l-4.595-6.623h4.379l2.459,3.648l2.433-3.648h4.244l-4.595,6.541l5.163,7.434h-4.379
        l-2.919-4.406l-2.919,4.406h-4.298L66.223,159.693z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M93.901,158.773H80.25v-2.893h13.651V158.773z M93.901,164.559H80.25v-2.893h13.651V164.559z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M104.361,150.908h-3.838v-3.163h3.838V150.908z M100.522,153.07h3.838v13.975h-3.838V153.07z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M106.847,153.07h3.649v1.945h0.081c0.973-1.567,2.649-2.324,4.271-2.324c4.082,0,5.108,2.298,5.108,5.758
        v8.596h-3.838v-7.893c0-2.298-0.676-3.434-2.46-3.434c-2.082,0-2.973,1.162-2.973,4.001v7.325h-3.839V153.07z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M132.309,165.261h-0.054c-0.892,1.514-2.459,2.163-4.244,2.163c-4.217,0-6.271-3.623-6.271-7.488
        c0-3.757,2.082-7.244,6.19-7.244c1.648,0,3.271,0.703,4.163,2.082h-0.027h0.054v-7.028h3.838v19.3h-3.649V165.261z
         M128.957,155.584c-2.514,0-3.379,2.162-3.379,4.46c0,2.189,1,4.487,3.379,4.487c2.541,0,3.298-2.217,3.298-4.515
        C132.255,157.746,131.444,155.584,128.957,155.584z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M141.471,160.99c0.108,2.433,1.297,3.541,3.433,3.541c1.541,0,2.784-0.946,3.027-1.811h3.379
        c-1.082,3.297-3.379,4.703-6.542,4.703c-4.406,0-7.136-3.027-7.136-7.353c0-4.19,2.892-7.38,7.136-7.38
        c4.757,0,7.055,4,6.785,8.299H141.471z M147.715,158.557c-0.352-1.945-1.189-2.973-3.055-2.973c-2.433,0-3.135,1.893-3.189,2.973
        H147.715z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M153.282,153.07h3.649v1.783h0.054c0.919-1.486,2.433-2.162,4.163-2.162c4.379,0,6.353,3.541,6.353,7.515
        c0,3.73-2.055,7.218-6.136,7.218c-1.676,0-3.271-0.73-4.19-2.109h-0.054v6.65h-3.839V153.07z M163.662,160.098
        c0-2.217-0.892-4.514-3.352-4.514c-2.514,0-3.325,2.244-3.325,4.514c0,2.271,0.865,4.434,3.352,4.434
        C162.852,164.531,163.662,162.369,163.662,160.098z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M172.419,160.99c0.108,2.433,1.297,3.541,3.433,3.541c1.541,0,2.784-0.946,3.027-1.811h3.379
        c-1.082,3.297-3.379,4.703-6.542,4.703c-4.406,0-7.136-3.027-7.136-7.353c0-4.19,2.892-7.38,7.136-7.38
        c4.757,0,7.055,4,6.785,8.299H172.419z M178.663,158.557c-0.352-1.945-1.189-2.973-3.055-2.973c-2.433,0-3.135,1.893-3.189,2.973
        H178.663z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M184.23,153.07h3.649v1.945h0.081c0.973-1.567,2.649-2.324,4.271-2.324c4.082,0,5.109,2.298,5.109,5.758
        v8.596h-3.838v-7.893c0-2.298-0.676-3.434-2.46-3.434c-2.081,0-2.973,1.162-2.973,4.001v7.325h-3.839V153.07z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M209.692,165.261h-0.054c-0.892,1.514-2.459,2.163-4.244,2.163c-4.217,0-6.271-3.623-6.271-7.488
        c0-3.757,2.081-7.244,6.19-7.244c1.649,0,3.271,0.703,4.163,2.082h-0.027h0.054v-7.028h3.838v19.3h-3.649V165.261z
         M206.34,155.584c-2.514,0-3.379,2.162-3.379,4.46c0,2.189,1,4.487,3.379,4.487c2.541,0,3.297-2.217,3.297-4.515
        C209.638,157.746,208.827,155.584,206.34,155.584z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M218.854,160.99c0.108,2.433,1.297,3.541,3.433,3.541c1.541,0,2.784-0.946,3.027-1.811h3.379
        c-1.082,3.297-3.379,4.703-6.542,4.703c-4.406,0-7.136-3.027-7.136-7.353c0-4.19,2.892-7.38,7.136-7.38
        c4.757,0,7.055,4,6.785,8.299H218.854z M225.098,158.557c-0.352-1.945-1.189-2.973-3.055-2.973c-2.433,0-3.135,1.893-3.189,2.973
        H225.098z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M230.666,153.07h3.649v1.945h0.081c0.973-1.567,2.649-2.324,4.271-2.324c4.082,0,5.109,2.298,5.109,5.758
        v8.596h-3.838v-7.893c0-2.298-0.676-3.434-2.46-3.434c-2.081,0-2.973,1.162-2.973,4.001v7.325h-3.838V153.07z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M251.019,153.07h2.811v2.567h-2.811v6.92c0,1.298,0.324,1.622,1.622,1.622c0.405,0,0.784-0.027,1.189-0.107v3
        c-0.649,0.107-1.487,0.135-2.244,0.135c-2.352,0-4.406-0.541-4.406-3.324v-8.245h-2.324v-2.567h2.324v-4.19h3.839V153.07z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M255.234,147.745h3.838v19.3h-3.838V147.745z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M268.452,168.802c-0.838,2.244-2.162,3.163-4.812,3.163c-0.784,0-1.568-0.055-2.352-0.136v-3.163
        c0.73,0.055,1.487,0.163,2.244,0.136c1.324-0.136,1.757-1.514,1.324-2.622l-4.919-13.109h4.109l3.163,9.568h0.054l3.055-9.568
        h3.974L268.452,168.802z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M288.805,152.691c4.406,0,7.244,2.92,7.244,7.38c0,4.433-2.838,7.353-7.244,7.353
        c-4.379,0-7.217-2.92-7.217-7.353C281.587,155.611,284.426,152.691,288.805,152.691z M288.805,164.531
        c2.622,0,3.406-2.244,3.406-4.46c0-2.243-0.784-4.487-3.406-4.487c-2.595,0-3.379,2.244-3.379,4.487
        C285.426,162.287,286.21,164.531,288.805,164.531z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M297.453,153.07h3.649v2.595h0.054c0.703-1.757,2.595-2.974,4.46-2.974c0.27,0,0.595,0.055,0.838,0.135v3.568
        c-0.352-0.08-0.919-0.135-1.379-0.135c-2.811,0-3.784,2.027-3.784,4.487v6.298h-3.839V153.07z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M320.861,166.152c0,2.299-0.811,6.19-7.245,6.19c-2.757,0-5.974-1.297-6.163-4.487h3.811
        c0.352,1.434,1.514,1.92,2.865,1.92c2.136,0,3.108-1.46,3.082-3.461v-1.838h-0.054c-0.838,1.461-2.514,2.163-4.19,2.163
        c-4.189,0-5.974-3.19-5.974-7.028c0-3.622,2.082-6.92,6.001-6.92c1.838,0,3.244,0.622,4.163,2.244h0.054v-1.865h3.649V166.152z
         M317.212,159.882c0-2.271-0.784-4.298-3.271-4.298c-2.163,0-3.109,1.893-3.109,3.974c0,2,0.757,4.189,3.109,4.189
        C316.131,163.747,317.212,161.882,317.212,159.882z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M322.698,157.368c0.216-3.595,3.433-4.677,6.568-4.677c2.785,0,6.136,0.622,6.136,3.974v7.271
        c0,1.271,0.135,2.541,0.487,3.108h-3.893c-0.135-0.432-0.243-0.893-0.27-1.352c-1.217,1.271-3.001,1.73-4.704,1.73
        c-2.649,0-4.757-1.324-4.757-4.19c0-3.162,2.378-3.919,4.757-4.243c2.352-0.352,4.541-0.271,4.541-1.838
        c0-1.649-1.135-1.893-2.487-1.893c-1.459,0-2.406,0.594-2.541,2.108H322.698z M331.564,160.206c-0.648,0.567-2,0.595-3.189,0.812
        c-1.189,0.243-2.271,0.648-2.271,2.054c0,1.433,1.108,1.784,2.352,1.784c3,0,3.108-2.379,3.108-3.217V160.206z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M337.834,153.07h3.649v1.945h0.081c0.973-1.567,2.649-2.324,4.271-2.324c4.082,0,5.108,2.298,5.108,5.758
        v8.596h-3.838v-7.893c0-2.298-0.676-3.434-2.459-3.434c-2.082,0-2.974,1.162-2.974,4.001v7.325h-3.838V153.07z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M356.727,150.908h-3.838v-3.163h3.838V150.908z M352.889,153.07h3.838v13.975h-3.838V153.07z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M358.349,164.152l7.271-8.189h-6.73v-2.893h11.785v2.893l-7.271,8.189h7.784v2.893h-12.839V164.152z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M375.864,160.99c0.108,2.433,1.298,3.541,3.433,3.541c1.541,0,2.785-0.946,3.028-1.811h3.378
        c-1.081,3.297-3.378,4.703-6.542,4.703c-4.406,0-7.136-3.027-7.136-7.353c0-4.19,2.893-7.38,7.136-7.38
        c4.758,0,7.055,4,6.786,8.299H375.864z M382.107,158.557c-0.351-1.945-1.189-2.973-3.054-2.973c-2.433,0-3.135,1.893-3.189,2.973
        H382.107z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M397.65,165.261h-0.054c-0.892,1.514-2.459,2.163-4.244,2.163c-4.217,0-6.271-3.623-6.271-7.488
        c0-3.757,2.082-7.244,6.19-7.244c1.648,0,3.271,0.703,4.163,2.082h-0.027h0.054v-7.028h3.839v19.3h-3.649V165.261z
         M394.298,155.584c-2.514,0-3.378,2.162-3.378,4.46c0,2.189,1,4.487,3.378,4.487c2.541,0,3.298-2.217,3.298-4.515
        C397.596,157.746,396.785,155.584,394.298,155.584z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M415.299,151.313h-5.784v-3.567h15.813v3.567h-5.785v15.732h-4.244V151.313z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M427.002,147.745h14.435v3.567h-10.19v4.137h9.353v3.297h-9.353v4.73h10.406v3.568h-14.65V147.745z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M443.436,147.745h8.326c5,0,8.758,3.136,8.758,9.542c0,5.596-2.865,9.758-8.758,9.758h-8.326V147.745z
         M447.68,163.477h3.784c2.459,0,4.812-1.514,4.812-5.784c0-3.893-1.352-6.38-5.569-6.38h-3.027V163.477z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M472.654,160.99c0.108,2.433,1.298,3.541,3.433,3.541c1.541,0,2.785-0.946,3.027-1.811h3.379
        c-1.081,3.297-3.379,4.703-6.542,4.703c-4.406,0-7.136-3.027-7.136-7.353c0-4.19,2.893-7.38,7.136-7.38
        c4.758,0,7.055,4,6.785,8.299H472.654z M478.898,158.557c-0.351-1.945-1.189-2.973-3.054-2.973c-2.433,0-3.136,1.893-3.189,2.973
        H478.898z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M491.656,167.045h-4.271l-4.784-13.975h4.027l2.946,9.541h0.054l2.946-9.541h3.812L491.656,167.045z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M500.062,160.99c0.108,2.433,1.298,3.541,3.433,3.541c1.541,0,2.785-0.946,3.028-1.811h3.378
        c-1.081,3.297-3.378,4.703-6.542,4.703c-4.406,0-7.136-3.027-7.136-7.353c0-4.19,2.893-7.38,7.136-7.38
        c4.758,0,7.055,4,6.785,8.299H500.062z M506.305,158.557c-0.351-1.945-1.189-2.973-3.054-2.973c-2.433,0-3.136,1.893-3.189,2.973
        H506.305z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M511.873,153.07h3.649v1.945h0.082c0.973-1.567,2.649-2.324,4.271-2.324c4.082,0,5.109,2.298,5.109,5.758
        v8.596h-3.838v-7.893c0-2.298-0.676-3.434-2.46-3.434c-2.082,0-2.974,1.162-2.974,4.001v7.325h-3.838V153.07z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M532.226,153.07h2.812v2.567h-2.812v6.92c0,1.298,0.325,1.622,1.622,1.622c0.406,0,0.784-0.027,1.189-0.107v3
        c-0.648,0.107-1.486,0.135-2.244,0.135c-2.352,0-4.406-0.541-4.406-3.324v-8.245h-2.325v-2.567h2.325v-4.19h3.838V153.07z"/>
</g>
</g>
<g>
<g>
    <path class="st1" d="M77.792,83.893H59.783V67.422h55.798v16.471H97.579v47.792H77.792V83.893z"/>
    <path class="st1" d="M118.657,67.422h54.166v16.471h-34.367V91.9h34.367v15.306h-34.367v8.008h34.376v16.47h-54.175V67.422z"/>
    <path class="st1" d="M176.155,67.422h32.491c21.417,0,28.986,15.841,28.986,32.037c0,19.716-10.44,32.225-32.852,32.225h-28.625
        V67.422z M195.953,115.214h7.743c12.333,0,14.137-9.994,14.137-16.03c0-4.042-1.267-15.292-15.579-15.292h-6.301V115.214z"/>
</g>
<g>
    <g>
        <path class="st1" d="M266.081,106.92l-6.04-10.015l-5.89,10.015h-14.506l13.771-20.251l-13.261-19.371h14.511l5.374,9.575
            l5.528-9.575h14.507l-13.257,19.371l13.771,20.251H266.081z"/>
    </g>
</g>
</g>
<g>
<path class="st1" d="M345.467,67.636v41.576c0,13.115-8.208,24.178-25.784,24.178c-17.219,0-24.624-11.063-24.624-23.019V67.636
    h8.654v40.327c0,13.918,8.476,17.754,16.238,17.754c7.94,0,16.862-3.658,16.862-17.576V67.636H345.467z"/>
<path class="st1" d="M396.229,131.695h-7.851v-28.728c0-8.119-2.32-12.223-9.993-12.223c-4.461,0-12.312,2.855-12.312,15.524
    v25.427h-7.851V85.034h7.405v6.602h0.179c1.695-2.498,6.067-7.94,14.096-7.94c7.227,0,16.327,2.944,16.327,16.238V131.695z"/>
<path class="st1" d="M408.003,76.558v-8.922h7.851v8.922H408.003z M415.854,131.695h-7.851V85.034h7.851V131.695z"/>
<path class="st1" d="M457.161,85.034h8.565l-17.754,46.661h-8.387l-17.041-46.661h9.1l12.134,38.007h0.178L457.161,85.034z"/>
<path class="st1" d="M509.62,117.063c-0.268,2.23-2.409,8.833-8.297,12.758c-2.141,1.427-5.175,3.212-12.669,3.212
    c-13.115,0-20.877-9.903-20.877-23.375c0-14.453,6.959-25.962,22.394-25.962c13.472,0,20.074,10.707,20.074,27.212h-34.082
    c0,9.725,4.55,15.345,13.562,15.345c7.405,0,11.776-5.71,12.044-9.189H509.62z M502.125,104.662
    c-0.446-7.227-3.479-13.918-13.025-13.918c-7.227,0-12.937,6.691-12.937,13.918H502.125z"/>
<path class="st1" d="M528.532,131.695h-7.852V85.034h7.405v7.762h0.178c3.123-5.442,7.227-9.101,13.115-9.101
    c0.981,0,1.428,0.089,2.052,0.268v8.119h-2.944c-7.316,0-11.955,5.71-11.955,12.49V131.695z"/>
<path class="st1" d="M575.816,98.327c-0.089-2.944-1.16-7.851-11.063-7.851c-2.409,0-9.279,0.803-9.279,6.602
    c0,3.836,2.409,4.729,8.476,6.245l7.851,1.963c9.725,2.409,13.115,5.978,13.115,12.312c0,9.636-7.94,15.435-18.468,15.435
    c-18.468,0-19.807-10.706-20.074-16.327h7.583c0.268,3.658,1.338,9.546,12.401,9.546c5.621,0,10.706-2.23,10.706-7.405
    c0-3.748-2.587-4.997-9.279-6.691l-9.1-2.23c-6.513-1.606-10.795-4.907-10.795-11.331c0-10.26,8.476-14.899,17.666-14.899
    c16.684,0,17.843,12.313,17.843,14.632H575.816z"/>
<path class="st1" d="M594.104,76.558v-8.922h7.851v8.922H594.104z M601.955,131.695h-7.851V85.034h7.851V131.695z"/>
<path class="st1" d="M623.365,91.547v30.334c0,3.658,3.123,3.658,4.729,3.658h2.766v6.156c-2.854,0.268-5.085,0.625-5.888,0.625
    c-7.763,0-9.457-4.372-9.457-9.992v-30.78h-6.335v-6.513h6.335V72.008h7.851v13.026h7.494v6.513H623.365z"/>
<path class="st1" d="M667.706,85.034h8.654c-5.442,15.256-10.796,30.513-16.773,45.769c-7.405,18.914-8.208,19.985-18.29,19.985
    c-1.159,0-2.052-0.357-3.301-0.714v-7.137c0.981,0.356,2.588,0.803,4.729,0.803c4.104,0,4.551-1.16,8.298-10.795l-17.309-47.91
    h8.922l12.401,38.007h0.179L667.706,85.034z"/>
<path class="st1" d="M700.359,83.695c14.899,0,21.68,12.58,21.68,24.625s-6.78,24.624-21.68,24.624s-21.68-12.58-21.68-24.624
    S685.46,83.695,700.359,83.695z M700.359,126.163c11.241,0,13.562-11.598,13.562-17.843c0-6.246-2.32-17.844-13.562-17.844
    s-13.562,11.598-13.562,17.844C686.798,114.565,689.118,126.163,700.359,126.163z"/>
<path class="st1" d="M740.685,91.547v40.148h-7.852V91.547h-6.424v-6.513h6.424v-8.03c0-7.048,4.461-10.26,12.134-10.26
    c1.159,0,2.319,0.089,3.568,0.178v7.048c-0.981-0.089-2.23-0.178-3.212-0.178c-3.39,0-4.639,1.695-4.639,5.442v5.799h7.851v6.513
    H740.685z"/>
<path class="st1" d="M809.471,131.695V93.866c0-1.874,0.178-9.992,0.178-15.97h-0.178l-18.022,53.798h-8.564l-18.022-53.709h-0.179
    c0,5.889,0.179,14.007,0.179,15.881v37.829h-8.387V67.636h12.401l18.29,54.155h0.179l18.2-54.155h12.312v64.059H809.471z"/>
<path class="st1" d="M829.809,99.219c0.357-11.152,7.763-15.524,19.271-15.524c3.747,0,17.309,1.071,17.309,13.026v26.855
    c0,1.962,0.981,2.766,2.587,2.766c0.714,0,1.695-0.179,2.587-0.357v5.71c-1.338,0.357-2.498,0.892-4.282,0.892
    c-6.959,0-8.029-3.569-8.297-7.137c-3.033,3.301-7.762,7.583-16.862,7.583c-8.565,0-14.632-5.442-14.632-13.472
    c0-3.925,1.16-13.026,14.186-14.632l12.937-1.606c1.874-0.178,4.104-0.892,4.104-5.531c0-4.907-3.569-7.583-10.974-7.583
    c-8.922,0-10.171,5.442-10.707,9.011H829.809z M858.537,107.874c-1.249,0.981-3.212,1.695-12.937,2.944
    c-3.837,0.535-9.992,1.695-9.992,7.583c0,5.085,2.587,8.119,8.476,8.119c7.315,0,14.453-4.729,14.453-10.974V107.874z"/>
<path class="st1" d="M908.854,100.736c-0.981-6.246-4.461-9.993-11.063-9.993c-9.725,0-12.847,9.279-12.847,17.576
    c0,8.029,1.962,17.933,12.758,17.933c5.264,0,9.813-3.925,11.152-11.063h7.583c-0.803,7.405-5.353,17.844-19.003,17.844
    c-13.115,0-20.877-9.903-20.877-23.375c0-14.453,6.959-25.962,22.394-25.962c12.223,0,16.862,8.922,17.486,17.041H908.854z"/>
<path class="st1" d="M963.9,117.063c-0.268,2.23-2.409,8.833-8.297,12.758c-2.142,1.427-5.175,3.212-12.67,3.212
    c-13.114,0-20.877-9.903-20.877-23.375c0-14.453,6.959-25.962,22.395-25.962c13.472,0,20.073,10.707,20.073,27.212h-34.081
    c0,9.725,4.55,15.345,13.562,15.345c7.405,0,11.776-5.71,12.044-9.189H963.9z M956.406,104.662
    c-0.446-7.227-3.479-13.918-13.026-13.918c-7.227,0-12.937,6.691-12.937,13.918H956.406z"/>
<path class="st1" d="M1012.611,131.695h-7.404v-6.424h-0.179c-3.391,6.334-8.743,7.762-13.294,7.762
    c-15.881,0-20.52-14.899-20.52-26.052c0-13.115,7.048-23.286,19.449-23.286c8.476,0,12.044,5.264,13.918,7.94l0.179-0.625V67.636
    h7.851V131.695z M991.913,126.252c4.996,0,12.758-3.301,12.758-15.702c0-7.583-1.249-19.807-12.579-19.807
    c-12.134,0-12.759,11.509-12.759,17.487C979.333,118.491,983.348,126.252,991.913,126.252z"/>
<path class="st1" d="M1042.498,83.695c14.899,0,21.68,12.58,21.68,24.625s-6.78,24.624-21.68,24.624s-21.68-12.58-21.68-24.624
    S1027.599,83.695,1042.498,83.695z M1042.498,126.163c11.241,0,13.562-11.598,13.562-17.843c0-6.246-2.32-17.844-13.562-17.844
    s-13.562,11.598-13.562,17.844C1028.937,114.565,1031.257,126.163,1042.498,126.163z"/>
<path class="st1" d="M1111.104,131.695h-7.851v-28.728c0-8.119-2.32-12.223-9.992-12.223c-4.461,0-12.313,2.855-12.313,15.524
    v25.427h-7.852V85.034h7.405v6.602h0.179c1.695-2.498,6.066-7.94,14.097-7.94c7.227,0,16.326,2.944,16.326,16.238V131.695z"/>
<path class="st1" d="M1122.88,76.558v-8.922h7.852v8.922H1122.88z M1130.731,131.695h-7.852V85.034h7.852V131.695z"/>
<path class="st1" d="M1142.238,99.219c0.357-11.152,7.763-15.524,19.271-15.524c3.747,0,17.309,1.071,17.309,13.026v26.855
    c0,1.962,0.981,2.766,2.587,2.766c0.714,0,1.695-0.179,2.587-0.357v5.71c-1.338,0.357-2.498,0.892-4.282,0.892
    c-6.959,0-8.029-3.569-8.297-7.137c-3.033,3.301-7.762,7.583-16.862,7.583c-8.565,0-14.632-5.442-14.632-13.472
    c0-3.925,1.16-13.026,14.186-14.632l12.937-1.606c1.874-0.178,4.104-0.892,4.104-5.531c0-4.907-3.569-7.583-10.974-7.583
    c-8.922,0-10.171,5.442-10.707,9.011H1142.238z M1170.967,107.874c-1.249,0.981-3.212,1.695-12.937,2.944
    c-3.837,0.535-9.992,1.695-9.992,7.583c0,5.085,2.587,8.119,8.476,8.119c7.315,0,14.453-4.729,14.453-10.974V107.874z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Also the github folder if you want to test it is : [GitHub](https://github.com/kosmastsk/ComingSoon-TEDxUoM2016/tree/472df9cb6f6173e7eb2a2aac054b6a24f5f4b270)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to add your .svg file in  tags in your HTML code. It will work then, if your svg code is fine.
That worked for me when I had a similar problem!

Answer (score 1):

You have a `@-webkit-keyframes`, which will work for Webkit browsers (including Chrome), but you don't have the corresponding keyframes variants for the other browsers.

In particular, for Mozilla, you will need an unprefixed `@keyframes` version of that rule.

```
@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 2000;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: can you see then the website project? works fine on mozilla when I open the .svg file, but this does not work when I use jQuery to show this image onload of my page on Mozilla

Comment: If you think it has some other cause, then you should ask a new question about that.  Remember to include a minimal example demonstrating the problem. No one will want to check-out your repo to test for you.